# React Native, Android build failing because of missing CMakeLists.txt

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm trying to build my react native project for Android but I get this error.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures. 

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1409] [project folder]/android/app/.cxx/Debug/l1z3g258/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json debug|arm64-v8a : expected buildFiles file '[project folder]/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt' to exist

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I get the same CMakeLists.txt missing error in Android Studio -> Build as well.

The library in the error, `react-native-screens`, was installed at one point but it is not something I'm using anymore. It is not part of my package.json file now. The only few references to this file that I can find in my project now is in the `[project fodler]/android/app/.cxx/debug` & `[project fodler]/android/app/wef/debug` folder. I'm not sure how to clean the reference here to not include libraries that are no longer installed in the project.

When I run `./gradlew clean` inside android folder I run into the same issue again.

Comment: did u find any answers?

Comment: @abdulsathar I just deleted the cxx folder and built it again. That worked. Not sure why but I have to keep deleting the cxx folder.

Comment: I found it is because u r using new architecture in React native project but some dependencies were missing from the new architecture installation. try to disable newArchEnabled=false or configure it better to work for new react native architecture.

Comment: @abdulsathar I already have newArchEnabled=false in the project. That does not seem to stop the cxx folder creation though.

Comment: it is working for me, may be u can do some clean cache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just remove android/app/.cxx folder and try to rebuild

Comment: it worked! thank you

Comment: the folder doesn't exist.